# Python assignment destructioning

Tags: python

How can I do the ES6 type object destructuring in Python?

```
dictionary = {}

dictionary['a'] = 'hello'
dictionary['b'] = 'goodbye'

print dictionary

a, b = [dictionary]

print a, b
```

How can I have it print `hello goodbye` ?

Comment: Technically speaking you can't, since the compiler doesn't care about the names on the LHS.

Comment: Too bad, it's a really nice ES6 feature. If you answer that I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: @cricket_007 The OP wants the variable `a` to become bound to the value of the key `a` in the dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can actually do this:

```
a, b = dictionary.values()
```

Or if you are worrying dictionary is not ordered, you can do:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

print "Hello World!\n"
dictionary = OrderedDict()  # <-------------

dictionary['a'] = 'hello'
dictionary['b'] = 'goodbye'

print dictionary

a, b = dictionary.values()

print a, b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can imitate object destructuring through `exec()`.

```
[exec("global %s; %s=%s" % (var,var,repr(val))) 
              for var,val in dictionary.items() if var.isidentifier()]

print(a)
#hello
```

For convenience, you can write a function to hide all technicalities:

```
def destructure(d):
    [exec("global %s; %s=%s" % (var,var,repr(val))) 
              for var,val in d.items() if var.isidentifier()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the set values of the `dictionary` by their keys:

```
dictionary = {}

dictionary['a'] = 'hello'
dictionary['b'] = 'goodbye'

print dictionary

a, b = dictionary['a'], dictionary['b']

print a, b
```

Dictionary doesn't keep the order of keys and values. This means you should keep it in mind if you need an ordered result of keys or values from a dictionary.

Comment: The point is to automate matching identifiers and dictionary keys.

Comment: @DYZ But if that is not possible, then why not give a alternative? Some times what the OP asks for is simply not possible. Post an answer that gives a possible alternative, IMO is just as valid as one that provides a solution.

Comment: I think it is possible (see my answer below).

Comment: @DYZ Ok, you have me there :) But the OP really should not be using your solution. In fact, you said so yourself. Why choose a hack over a slightly different method that is much more idiomatic?

Comment: @leaf Actually, I disagree. I believe I made my solution almost safe.